# How do I get GCM registration ID from GCMIntent services to my MainActivity?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application in which I am using GCM for push notifications. I have a `MainActivity` in which I try to register the device as given below in `onCreate()` method.

```
        String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) 
        {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, "My sender id");        
        }
        else
        {
            GCMIntentService.received=true;

        }

        while(!GCMIntentService.received)
        {
            Log.i("RegisterLocation","waiting...... for registartion id");

        }
```

I am unable to get Registartion ID in `MainActivity`, but control is going to `OnRegistered(context,String)` function in `GCMIntentService` class, which is a sub-class of `GCMBaseIntentService`, when the device is registered. 
I am able to print registration id in Log also.

```
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) 
{
    received=true;
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}
```

Since GCM takes some time to register a device, I wrote that while loop to test whether the device is registered or not. But that loop is an infinite loop. I tried `Thread.sleep()` also. I want that registration id to store in my local server.
Can any one suggest a solution to get the registration id in my `MainActivity`?

Comment: Registration id will always go in `GCMIntentSerfice` under `onRegistered` function.

Comment: Either you can save registeration id in local database or call service and perform the necessary operation. What exactly you want to do with registration id in `MainActivity`?

Comment: @Mitesh I want to save that registration Id in my database so that I can use in further

Comment: I hope you've got the answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to do all the operations in `Service` class.

Call the [**service**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html) once the registration id is received in `GCMIntentService`.

I've done same way and it works smoothly..

Happy coding :)

Comment: Its fine but how do I use progress bar in 'GCMIntentService' class so that the user feels that application is running. I can not get the context  of 'Activity class' in 'GCMIntentService' class.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest that you do all the logic for storing the registration id in your server in the `onRegistered` method, and not in your main activity.

The reason that your loop doesn't work has to do with the [Java memory model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) :

> It is important to note that neither Thread.sleep nor Thread.yield
>   have any synchronization semantics. In particular, the compiler does
>   not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory
>   before a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield, nor does the compiler
>   have to reload values cached in registers after a call to Thread.sleep
>   or Thread.yield.
>
> For example, in the following (broken) code fragment, assume that
>   this.done is a non-volatile boolean field:

```
 while (!this.done)
     Thread.sleep(1000);
```

> The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse
>   the cached value in each execution of the loop. This would mean that
>   **the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the
>   value of this.done**.

The `this.done` field in this example behaves the same as your `GCMIntentService.received`. If you make it volatile it should work. That said, I wouldn't recommend having that loop in your main activity.

Comment: I declared it as volatile. but still it is an infinite loop.

Comment: I thought that would work. Perhaps you should try to access and modify the `received` member through synchronized methods. Anyway, even if it works, it's not considered a good practice to have such a loop in your activity.